# Creating a random matrix in python

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to create a random square matrix of nxn random numbers with numpy. Of course I am able to generate enough random numbers but I am having trouble using numpy to create a matrix of variable length. This is as far as I have gotten thus far:

```
def testMatrix(size):
    a = []
    for i in range(0, size*size):
        a.append(randint(0, 5))
```

How can I put this list into an array of size x size?

Comment: What about ```numpy.random.randint(0, 5, size=(s,s))```? Other approaches would be for example ```numpy.array(a).reshape((s,s))``` (if a is flat = 1d).

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
np.random.randint(0, 5, size=(s, s))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your test matrix is currently one dimensional. If you want to create a random matrix with numpy, you can just do:

```
num_rows = 3
num_columns = 3
random_matrix = numpy.random.random((num_rows, num_columns))
```

The result would be:

```
array([[ 0.15194989,  0.21977027,  0.85063633],
   [ 0.1879659 ,  0.09024749,  0.3566058 ],
   [ 0.18044427,  0.59143149,  0.25449112]])
```

You can also create a random matrix without numpy:

```
import random

num_rows = 3
num_columns = 3
random_matrix = [[random.random() for j in range(num_rows)] for i in range(num_columns)]
```

The result would be:

```
[[0.9982841729782105, 0.9659048749818827, 0.22838327707784145], 
[0.3524666409224604, 0.1918744765283834, 0.7779130503458696], 
[0.5239230720346117, 0.0224389713805887, 0.6547162177880549]]
```

Per the comments, I've added a function to convert a one dimensional array to a matrix:

```
def convert_to_matrix(arr, chunk_size):
    return [arr[i:i+chunk_size] for i in range(0, len(arr), chunk_size)]

arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
matrix = convert_to_matrix(arr, 3)
# [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]] is the output
```

Comment: That solution works perfectly for the question asked thanks! How would I modify that approach if my array was like a set of unique numbers 0 to n*n in a shuffled order. Is there a way to wrap an array into a numpy matrix?

Comment: @J.Doe If I'm understanding correctly, you want to take a shuffled one dimensional array and turn it into a numpy matrix? i.e. turn `[4,3,2,1]` into `array([[4,3],[2,1]])`

Comment: Sure that would accomplish it

Comment: @J.Doe Will add to my answer